# sql join two tables without keys

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a flat file that contains 'father and child' rows:
In common every row has this 2 columns:

> type_record
>
> progressive

father (row) type_record's value is **'01'**
instead child (row) its type_record's values is **'02'**

progressive it's just like a counter

here's a snap of the file (ignore whitespace)

https://pastebin.com/raw/tmpWfFiX

```
01 00001   father-columns................ --new father
02 00001   child columns.................
02 00001   child columns.................
02 00001   child columns.................

01 00002   fathercolumns................. --new father
02 00002   child columns.................
02 00002   child columns.................
02 00002   child columns.................

01 00003   fathercolumns................. --new father
02 00003   child columns.................
02 00003   child columns.................

01 00001   fathercolumns................. --new father (identical as the row before)
02 00001   child columns.................
02 00001   child columns.................
```

So I need to create a relation between those two tables

How could I do that?

Thanks

Edit:

I have created two separated external tables, one for father rows and one for children.

as you could expect too read the rows, i'm using **LOAD_WHEN = 'progressive'.**
Here's the create table to read the father rows

```
CREATE TABLE "EXT_FATHER" 
(
    "type_record"   VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
    "progressive"   VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
    "fields_other1" VARCHAR2(7 BYTE),
    "fields_other2" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)) 
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
    (
      TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY "DIR"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS ( 
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
        BADFILE DIR:'file.bad'
        LOGFILE DIR:'file.log'
        DISCARDFILE DIR:'file.dsc'
```

> ```
>         LOAD WHEN type_record = '01'
> ```

```
        FIELDS
        (
         type_record POSITION(1:2)    CHAR(2),
         progressive POSITION(3:5)    CHAR(5),
         fields_other1 POSITION(8:7)  CHAR(7),
         fields_other2 POSITION(15:6) CHAR(6)
        .....
        )
  ) LOCATION ( "DIR":'  file.txt' ) 
);
```

---

Here's the create table to read the child rows

```
CREATE TABLE "EXT_CHILD" 
(
        "type_record"   VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
        "progressive"   VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
        "fields_other1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
        "fields_other2" VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)) 
        ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
        (
          TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY "DIR"
          ACCESS PARAMETERS ( 
            RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
            BADFILE DIR:'file.bad'
            LOGFILE DIR:'file.log'
            DISCARDFILE DIR:'file.dsc'
```

> ```
>             LOAD WHEN type_record = '02'
> ```

```
            FIELDS
            (
             type_record POSITION(1:2)    CHAR(2),
             progressive POSITION(3:5)    CHAR(5),
             fields_other1 POSITION(8:20) CHAR(20),
             fields_other2 POSITION(28:9) CHAR(9)
            .....
            )
      ) LOCATION ( "DIR":'  file.txt' ) 
    );
```

So taking in example the data as put as sample, (check please pastebin)
a query to getting the father rows would be

```
SELECT * FROM EXT_FATHER WHERE PROGRESSIVE = '00001'
```

this would produce a result set of 2 rows...**but I need to be 'UNIQUE'**

because then I need to get the childer

the second query would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM EXT_CHILD WHERE PROGRESSIVE = '00001'
```

but this would procude a result **set of 5 rows..3** of the first father then the last of the **second father**

Comment: Just to make the scenario clearer, are you planning to import that file's content into actual tables or do you want to just read the file from the external tables you're creating?

Comment: I will create a procedure that loops these tables and import into anothers one doing some logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like Oracle, so I'll assume you're using an Oracle database.

If you want to join the two tables, you will need some sort of key, be it a composite or a surrogate one. If there's no way you can find a composite key with the fields in that file, you will have to generate a surrogate one.

I'm not an expert in external tables, but the steps I'd try to follow if trying to do what you need would be

1. create a [sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) `temp_load_seq`;
2. load the whole file into an external table `temp_tab`, using `temp_load_seq.nextval()` on each row to save the ordering; this would give me a table that looks like the file, with an added "artificial row number";
3. create another sequence `surrogate_key_seq`;
4. create my final tables `fathers_tab` and `children_tab`; the first one would have an additional `id` column, the second would have an additional `father_id` column;
5. write a procedure that loops through `temp_tab` and inserts its rows into either `fathers_tab` or `children_tab` depending on `type_record` value;

   1. when inserting into `fathers_tab` I would populate its `id` field with `surrogate_key_seq.nextval()`;
   2. when inserting into `children_tab` I would populate its `father_id` field with `surrogate_key_seq.currval()`.

This way the final tables could be easily filtered and joined on `id` and `father_id`.

I'm not 100% sure step 2 would be feasible, because of the usage of a sequence in an external table, but from [this article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:30572233529536) it seems it should be fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Gonna test it and let you know

Comment: I've created a control file then used sqloader

Thank you for tips